# Markov Chain, absorbing probability and expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n\}_{n = 0,1,\ldots}$ be a DTMC with state space $S = \{0,\ldots,M-1,M,\ldots,N\}$, where $0,1,\ldots,M-1$ are transient states and $\{M,\ldots,N\}$ are absorbing states. Hence the transition matrix has a block structure:
$P = \begin{pmatrix}  Q & R \\
0 & I \end{pmatrix}$

Let $T:= min\{n \ge 0 : M \le X_T \le N\}$ be the absorbing time, and let $\underline{\alpha_0}$ be the initial distribution.

(1) Find $P(T > k, X_T = j)$ for $k = 0,1,2,\ldots$, $j = M,\ldots,N$

(2) Find $E[T|X_T = j]$ for $j = M,\ldots,N$

Here is my trial for (1): since $P(X_T = j, T > k) = \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} P(X_T = j, T = n)$, and for each $n$, $P(X_T = j, T = n) = \sum_{x_0 \in [0,M-1]}\sum_{x_1 \in M-1}\ldots \sum_{x_{n-1} \in [0,M-1]}P(X_0 = x_0,\ldots,X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},X_n = j) \\
= \sum_{x_0 \in [0,M-1]}\sum_{x_1 \in M-1}\ldots \sum_{x_{n-1}} \alpha_{0,x_0} P_{x_0,x_1} \ldots P_{x_{n-2},x_{n-1}} P_{x_{n-1},j} \\
= \underline{\alpha_0}' Q^{n-1} R_j$

Where $\underline{\alpha_{0}}'$ is a row vector consist of the first $M$ entries from the initil distribution and $R_j$ is the $j-th$ column from matrix $R$

Can someone check the correctness of my solution? Thanks! Also, I appreciate your help for part (2)